# Limited pixel values in layer effects and styles (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, styles, layers

Some layer effects and styles in Photoshop have pixel settings. The problem appears when you want to scale your design. For example, in `Bevel and Emboss` you are able to set the `Size` and `Soften`. The former is limited to `250px` and the latter to `16px`.

To scale and preserve my design I need to set values greater than the Photoshop limits. Is it possible to do that? Any workaround?

Moving to Illustrator is not a solution, since some Photoshop effects that I'm using are not present in Illustrator.

Comment: Um. How big are we talking here, exactly? In 12 years of professional graphic design I've never had a problem with these limits.

Comment: 1m x 1m at 300dpi = 11811 x 11811px

Comment: At 1m x 1m you shouldn't be working at 300dpi. No poster of that size, or larger, that you see printed anywhere (film posters, banners, etc) is ever worked on at that resolution. You should be working 50% or 25% of the original, and indicate to your printers that you want it printed 1m x 1m. Keep any vector elements (eg. fonts) as vector, and they will remain pin-sharp once printed fullsize.

Comment: Yes, I send big files with 150dpi, my comment was wrong. The question remains, a file of 2m x 2m at 150dpi = 11811 x 11811px.

Comment: A 2m x 2m 150dpi file would print 4m x 4m. Are you sure you've calculated this correctly?

Comment: I came across your question in the unanswered questions pool.  The question is about 16 months old.  It looks like the only activity you got was the interaction with Django half a year after posting, which didn't go anywhere.  Can you update the status?  Did you ever find a solution?  Still need a solution?  Was the problem overtaken by events and no longer needs solving?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that most large format prints are meant to be viewed from quite a distance, state of the art large format inkjet printers today have enough resolution to print near photo realistic quality. I am working on a logo right now that will be displayed nine feet tall and be viewed from as few as three feet. It has an area with complex bevels that will be nearly the full height of the print. The bevels could be reproduced in Illustrator, but the time required would be huge.

35 years ago we had to create these effects with a REAL airbrush  :-)

- Keep your original large image file.
- Decide how much more than 200 px you need and reduce a copy of your file by the the reverse percentage.
- Isolate the areas you want to apply different effects to in separate layers.
- Apply the effects to the desired result.
- Isolate each layer with effects, flatten your artwork and save each layer as a separate file.
- Open each saved, flatten, layer file and enlarge it to the desired size.
- Use blurring and smudging to clean if necessary. You likely won't need much of this except at corners.
- Cut out the effected area from the flatten art (solid color background makes this easy) and paste back into the original (or copy) of your hi-res file.
  Photoshop does a real good job of enlarging images that have clean lines and smooth gradients.